# Difference between TextBox and RichTextBox in regards to threading

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, textbox, richtextbox

I hit a problem and I thought it might be due to the complexity of my classes passing objects to each other so I minimised it and the problem persists:

I've got a default winform project created in VS2017 Community

On the form I've added a textbox, a richtextbox, a backgroundworker and a button to activate the background worker.

I've put the following code in the form to populate the text boxes and to run the worker on button click:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        textBox1.Text = "Hello";
        richTextBox1.Text = "World!";
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (backgroundWorker1.IsBusy != true)
        {
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(textBox1.Text);
        MessageBox.Show(richTextBox1.Text);
    }
}
```

I run the program and I don't understand what happens next.

`textBox1.Text` is accessible from the form so the `MessageBox` shows fine. `richTextBox1.Text` is NOT accessible and gives me this error:

> Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'richTextBox1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

**WHY?**

I'm assuming richTextBox has more routing and wrapping but is the `.Text` property not exactly the same?! What's going on here?

**EDIT:** I don't think this is a duplicate to the marked question because his wasn't working for `TextBox.Text` whereas mine is. I'm asking about the DIFFERENCE BETWEEN TextBox and RichTextBox .Text properties.

Comment: Never access UI thread elements from a background thread. Neither `TextBox` nor `RichTextBox`. The code in your `DoWork` handler is definitely wrong. You should use `ReportProgress` and do your things there.

Comment: Yes I'm aware, and I actually pass things via arguments as I run the async worker. This is old code I'm looking at and I'd still like an answer to my question!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cross-thread operation not valid: Control accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142003/cross-thread-operation-not-valid-control-accessed-from-a-thread-other-than-the)

Comment: The answer is UI controls aren't thread safe, as to how they react, its unpredictable, there is nothing more to be said.

Comment: `TextBox` *works* by coincidence, you are *lucky* what current implementation doesn't throw. You shouldn't be relying on such *tests*. All UI elements have to be accessed from same thread they were created with.

Comment: You can [see in the Reference Source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,f12a8fdec6c1bb36) that the underlying `WindowText` _seems_ to be somewhat thread-safe.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They have been implemented differently.

`TextBox.Text` basically returns `Control.Text` which calls [`WindowText`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,4495) which uses `GetWindowText`.
 in the code comments clearly mentioned *it's okay to call GetWindowText cross-thread.* So they've turned off checking for cross-thread on purpose by setting a flag `inCrossThreadSafeCall`.

But for `ReachTextBox.Text` it doesn't rely on `Control.Text`. [It](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/RichTextBox.cs,1467) sends `EM_STREAMOUT` and uses the result. So no flag has been set to except this from cross-thread exception.

**Note:** You should ignore such cases and you should never try to access UI element from another thread. Always use `Invoke` method of the control when you are trying to interact with UI thread from another thread.

Comment: THANK YOU. I already knew what everyone was telling me about not referring to UI elements in threads. I either pass the UI threads as arguments or in some cases have used invoke. I'm glad its confirmed that `.Text` properties do not come from the same place.

Comment: Check for cross-thread operation happens in `Handle` of control by checking if `checkForIllegalCrossThreadCalls && !inCrossThreadSafeCall && InvokeRequired`  is true, then throws the exception. For `WindowText` property it has been turned off by setting `inCrossThreadSafeCall` to true.

Answer (score 1):

You have to `Invoke` UI code (you can't run UI in the thread other than UI):

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
   // What to do with UI
   Action action = () => {
      MessageBox.Show(textBox1.Text);
      MessageBox.Show(richTextBox1.Text);
   }

   if (InvokeRequired)  // We are in some background thread, Invoke required
     Invoke(action);
   else                 // We are in UI (main) thread, just call the action
     action(); 
}
```

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.